# decreasing sifr render time

Tags: javascript, flash, sifr, render, lag

I'm using sifr for a few items on this page: http://blueprint.staging.dante-studios.com/public/templates/home.php

unfortunately it seems that the rendering is very slow, does anyone have any idea of how to:

a) speed up the rendering process
b) hide all "to be sifr'd" items until all of them are ready?

Comment: I think you mean DECREASING sifr render time.

Comment: FYI it loaded very quickly the first time for me (<1s), and almost instantly the subsequent loads.

Comment: yes, what a silly mistake to have made about decrease/increase.

On our tests here it was taking between 3->4 seconds for full page render. how long did it take you?

Comment: sIFR sucks.  Flash doesn't work on 64-bit browser, so your site looks horrible for me.  Use images instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions:

- The Flash movie has the bold and italic and bold + italic glyphs embedded. If you don't need those, they're adding needless weight to the movie. Same goes for other characters.
- You could get rid of all JavaScript comments in the `sifr-config` file.
- Flash transparency is not advised as it's a bit heavier to render.
- To improve the initial display, look into [ratios](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/Ratio+Calculation)
- Try loading the sIFR code before jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Yes.. I’ve used sIFR in many times and help me so much.. Visitors said rendering is very slow too. I has one solution which change to **[Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)**.

Cufon is more exciting because, it doesn’t use any browser plugins. Cufon, on the other hand just needs JavaScript to be enabled. Just a suggestion ;)

[Cufon Demo](http://www.cameronmoll.com/articles/cufon/)

Comment: looks very interesting, i'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

There is a performance penalty associated with SIFR. Unfortunately the speed is partially dependent on the speed of the client computer. The only way to improve times is to reduce the use of SIFR, or remove it altogether and use images to ensure fonts render the way you want them to.

Also, make sure that your font files only include the letters you are using, to reduce download time.

Comment: I'm currently on a vista ultimate computer with a 5.9 rating. So i can't really go any more powerfull for it to have an effect.

The flash file only has the alpha numeric values i'll be using.

But still i think there must be some means of resolving this, even if it's a "preloading" of sort to hide the effect of the page rendering per item.

Your comment is helpful but i've done most of those items short of not using sifr :/